# Why did Werner Herzog play Zec?

Tags: production, casting, jack-reacher

While watching [*Jack Reacher*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0790724/) I realized that *Werner Herzog* was playing the role of *Zec*. But why would such a famous arthouse director (whom I remember of not being particularly fond of mainstream Hollywood cinema) play a supporting role in a movie like that. Is there some interesting backstory behind this (maybe he is a fan of the books?) or was it just the usual business?

Comment: Wait til you see his [cameo](http://blogs.indiewire.com/theplaylist/watch-werner-herzogs-hilarious-cameo-on-parks-and-recreation-with-chris-pratt-and-aubrey-plaza-20150115) on parks and rec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From an [interview](http://www.guardian.co.uk/film/2012/dec/20/werner-herzog-jack-reacher) with Werner Herzog:

> I was approached by the director and Tom Cruise. They wanted me. I
>   think it's a logical idea because I've done parts before where I
>   played really dysfunctional and outrageous and dangerous characters,
>   like in Harmony Korine's Julien Donkey Boy, and because of that and
>   other films they were interested in me. And I liked them for their
>   professionalism and commitment – things that I prize myself.